# LOCK HINT MS-SQL Server, Slick and Scala

Tags: sql-server, scala, slick

I am trying to run the below query inside my app. Could somebody please explain what will happen if 2 threads try to select the same row, as apparently selection is allowed in all the below hints. We are seeing a lot of deadlock inside the transaction which first takes this lock and does some stuff.Thanks!

```
select  a, b, c, d, created_time, updated_time
          from lock_table
              with (ROWLOCK,UPDLOCK,HOLDLOCK)
               where a = $a
               AND b = $b
               AND c = $c
               AND d = $d.as[LockTableDetails]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could somebody please explain what will happen if 2 threads try to select the same row

Assuming

1. both sessions have started a [transaction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/understanding-transactions?view=sql-server-ver15#using-local-transactions) before this statement
2. both sessions supply exactly the same parameter values
   and
3. both sessions use query plans that read the same index

The first session will acquire an update (U) lock on each row of the index read by the query (and possibly a range lock if there are no matching rows).  These locks will be held for the duration of the transaction, and the second session will block.

If you're seeing unexpected concurrent execution here it's likely because you aren't using parameters, and instead using Scala string interpolation.  When you paste strings into a SQL query the two sessions are sending *different* queries that get *different* execution plans, lock *different* indexes and proceed to deadlock.

The query should use parameters, eg:

```
select  a, b, c, d, created_time, updated_time
          from lock_table
              with (ROWLOCK,UPDLOCK,HOLDLOCK)
               where a = @a
               AND b = @b
               AND c = @c
               AND d = @d.as[LockTableDetails]
```

and execute using a [preparedStatement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/reference/sqlserverpreparedstatement-class?view=sql-server-ver15).  Then the sessions will actually be executing the *same* query, and will get the same execution plan.

If this doen't fix the deadlock, post the deadlock XML and additional details about the concurrent transactions.

Comment: I use sql interpolator. So, the code somewhat looks like:

`sql"""select  a, b, c, d, created_time, updated_time
          from lock_table
              with (ROWLOCK,UPDLOCK,HOLDLOCK)
               where a = $a
               AND b = $b
               AND c = $c
               AND d = $d""".as[LockTableDetails]`

Comment: Then post the deadlock XML.  It will show whether parameter replacement occurred, as well as the reason for the deadlock.

Comment: Resolved the issue. There were too many indices defined on the table due to which inserts were slow. So, data which shouldn't have been on the same page for long were staying there and the select query from application's different threads was leading to a deadlock.